# Programmatically fire off alarm to CloudWatch when condition is met

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm researching the AWS CloudWatch SDK for Java and I see there's a limit of 5,000 alarms per account per region for `PutMetricAlarm`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

My situation is such that the number of alarms could potentially surpass this limit (i.e. transaction fails for a particular product). I wouldn't need to configure thresholds for a predetermined set of alarms. Rather, the alarm would be fired off ad hoc programmatically at the time failure is detected, with different failure possibilities that could reach well over 5,000.

Does CloudWatch support this scenario, either through `PutMetricAlarm` or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Increase your account limits (contact the AWS support)
- Use [SetAlarmState API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_SetAlarmState.html)